# How can a simple "select binary from agents" query have a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am confused as to why this simple sql query is getting a syntax error.  Is `binary` a reserved word? If so how do I deal with that?

```
show tables
+-------------------------------+
| Tables_in_neutron             |
+-------------------------------+
| agents                        |
              ...
| vips                          |
+-------------------------------+
desc agents
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | varchar(36)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| agent_type          | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| binary              | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| topic               | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| host                | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| admin_state_up      | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at          | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| started_at          | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| heartbeat_timestamp | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description         | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| configurations      | varchar(4095) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
select binary from agents
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from agents' at line 1
```

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT \`binary\` FROM \`agents\`;` would answer your question...

Comment: Binary is a type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BINARY is a reserved word. It is a data type, as @BenaminS linked to.

You can use reserved words by delimiting them in back-quotes (or double-quotes if you set SQL_MODE=ANSI OR ANSI_QUOTES). Delimited identifiers also lets you use special characters and whitespace in your identifiers.

You can check the list of MySQL's reserved words here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html